# Can I delete nvme0n1 from EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am currently using c5d.xlarge instance with NVMe 100GB from Amazon EC2 server, and I don't want the EBS to be used since it charges me some money. Currently, it seems like 9GB of EBS is mounted on my server.

Is it okay to remove nvme0n1 so that I do not get charged from EBS, and use nvme1n1 instead?

How can I remove nvme0n1?

Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2gFE.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove `nvme0n1` as this is your **root** EBS volume  storing  your operating system, boot partition and applications.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it also impossible to change nvme1n1 as a root and delete nvme0n1?

Comment: @RickShin You have to re-install everything yourself on a new instance. And anyway, 9GB volume will cost a fraction of what your EC2 costs in the first place.

Comment: `$0.08 x 9 = $0.72/month` -- Not worth worrying about.